# "Fehlen" weak, "empfehlen" strong. But "finden" and "empfinden" both strong. Cases when [some_verb] conjugates differently from [prefix+some_verb]?

Tags: prefix, conjugation, irregular-verb

Compare this pair:

> [finden](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/finden.html) - strong conjugation
>
> [empfinden](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/empfinden.html) - strong conjugation [exactly the same]

With this pair:

> [fehlen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/fehlen.html) - weak conjugation
>
> [empfehlen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/empfehlen.html) - strong conjugation [different]

The "finden/empfinden" situation (ie, where `some_verb` and `prefix+some_verb` have the exact same conjugation) is the normal one, right?

Are there any other `some_verb`'s that have the "fehlen/empfehlen" situation instead? (ie, where `some_verb` and `prefix+some_verb` conjugate *differently*?)

[There's [befehlen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/befehlen.html), of course, which conjugates exactly the same as "empfehlen", but that's still with `some_verb = "fehlen"`.

So I guess you could say that I'm looking for cases where:

`(some_verb).conjugation   !=   (prefix + some_verb).conjugation`

but

`some_verb != "fehlen"`

[edit: also cases where

`(some_prefix + some_verb).conjugation   !=   (different_prefix + some_verb).conjugation` ]
]

More examples that are at least *kinda* the same as the pattern I'm looking for (from chirlu's answer):

> [einweichen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/einweichen.html) weak
>
> [weichen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/weichen.html),
>   [zurückweichen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/zuru%3Ackweichen.html) strong
>
> [beringen](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-beringen.html) weak
>
> [ringen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/ringen.html),
>   [erringen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/erringen.html) strong
>
> [schallen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/schallen.html),
>   [beschallen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/beschallen.html) can both be either strong *or* weak
>
> [schaffen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/schaffen.html) can be strong or weak, depending...
>
> (If it means "create", it's strong.
>
> If it means "finish", it's weak.")
>
> [abschaffen](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/German/abschaffen.html) weak
>
> [erschaffen](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-erschaffen.html) strong

Comment: There's even a word "some_verb" = "some_verb" where "some_verb".conjugation != "some_verb".conjugation. The difference is its meaning. Unfortunately, I can't come up with this word off the top of my head.

Comment: well, befehlen and empfehlen are not really ... let me call it "related" to fehlen. that are not really prefixes. no, they are no prefixes at all :) thats why they conjugate differently. [here](http://web.hszg.de/~bgriebel/praefixe.html) are some prefixes. using these will keep the conugation the same (like the root word)

Comment: How are "be" and "emp" no prefixes? The second line of your own source calls "ver" a prefix.... case in point. They definitely are prefixes.
@ Em: try "schaffen"... you'll find what you seek :)

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, you example of "be-...", you should maybe read what the site said: "Einige Wortbestandteile sehen zwar aus wie Präfixe, sie sind jedoch nicht mehr als Präfixe anzusehen (z.B. beschäftigen, bestätigen, vergeuden), weil der Stamm ohne Präfix nicht frei im Satz verwendet werden kann." which just means that not EVERY be+XXXX is a prefix. this does not mean that "be-..." is not a prefix. if you would have read the site you would have noticed, that "be-..." is mentured as prefix in the table shown.

Comment: @user1451340 I read the site, but obviously I scrolled over *be-*. Still, you yourself said in your comment that the *be-* in *befehlen* and *emp-* in *empfehlen* are not prefixes.

Comment: für this particular case, they are not. (Befehl, Empfehlung)

Comment: @Em1: the classical example is "hängen" (transitive vs. intransitive). That's indeed the same pattern as in "einweichen" vs. "zurückweichen".

Comment: I don't think that it benefits anyone to call be a prefix sometimes and not a prefix at other times depending on whether the following verb can stand alone or not. In either case, the be- comes from the same origin, adds the same flavor to the whole verb and has the same grammatical implications... so it is the essentially the same thing - a non-separable prefix.

Answer (score 10):

*fehlen* and *empfehlen* do not derive from the same base (*fehlen*).

The verb *fehlen* derives from the old form *vælen* or *vēlen*, which means *to miss (a target)*. *Empfehlen* on the other hand derives from the verb *fel(a)han*, which means *to sow* or *to entrust*.

*finden* and *empfinden* do derive from *finden*, that's why they share the same conjugation.

Comment: Thanks, that etymological explanation for *why* the "fehlen/empfehlen" situation exists is good to know... **but it isn't an answer to the question, see?** The question is: does the same situation occur with any *other* `some_verb`s than "fehlen"? (For our purposes here, `some_verb` is defined as a string of letters, regardless of etymology, so the "fehlen" in "fehlen", "empfehlen", and "befehlen" is the "same".)

Comment: What I'm telling you is that your assumption is wrong in the first place! *fehlen/empfehlen* is not at all a "*[prefix + verb] conjugates differently than [verb]*" case, as *empfehlen* != *prefix* + *fehlen*!

Comment: From the point of view of synchronic analysis, they do belong together.

Comment: Well, that's like comparing *sein* in *krank sein* with the *sein* in *sein Auto*. They are different words. Wondering why you can not say *empfehlte* would be like wondering why you can not say *krank unser*. (I know that here I'm providing different word types, but you get the analogy).

Comment: The `Verb` class is separate from the `Pronoun` class, so that kinda synonym won't be an issue in my code... I totally get your point, it's just that basically the reason I'm asking is that I need to *handle* the fact that `"empfehlen" != prefix + "fehlen"` *somehow or other*, as it "looks like" an exception to a general rule that `prefix+some_verb` conjugates the same as `some_verb` by itself... So I need to know some more examples of that kind of exception so I can figure out how they work, see if there are any subtypes I'll need to handle etc...

Answer (score 6):

There are more examples, but they are of the same type (etymologically unrelated, as Thorsten Dittmar explained for *fehlen/empfehlen*):

- *(zurück)weichen* (*ich wich (zurück)*) vs. *einweichen* (*ich weichte ein*)
- *(er)ringen* (*ich (er)rang*) vs. *beringen* (*ich beringte*)
- *(er)schallen* (*es (er)scholl*) vs. *beschallen* (*ich beschallte*)

There are also verbs that follow different conjugations depending on their meaning, such as *schaffen*. Both forms can get prefixes: *erschaffen* (*ich erschuf*) vs. *abschaffen* (*ich schaffte ab*).

Comment: According to DWDS, the past form of *erschallen* is *erschallte*, so that doesn't fit here. Also (to be as strict as the OP wants to), none of your examples answers the question, which is for *[prefix] + [verb] != [verb]* and not *[prefix a] + [verb] != [prefix b] + [verb]*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar (be)-ringen and (ein)-weichen are two excellent examples. What's the problem with these?

Comment: *Schallen* is both strong and weak. [Example](http://www.epochtimes.de/articles/2008/08/07/323179p.html): Lautstark scholl es über die Brücke, die Falun Gong Anhänger schwiegen zunächst konzentriert wie in einer Meditation.

Comment: Yes, *(be-)ringen* and *(ein-)weichen* are two good examples, but as the answer is worded he's comparing *zurückweichen* to *einweichen* and *erringen* to *beringen*, which is not what the OP is asking for. However, *beringen* vs. *ringen* and *einweichen* vs. *weichen* would be good examples.

Comment: @Thorsten, the prefixes are optional (that’s why I put them in parentheses).

Comment: But as you can see, it's easily misunderstood.

Comment: @Em1 As *Schallen* is both strong and weak, it's a Schroedinger Example, right? It's both good and bad :-D

Comment: No, that's helpful, thanks... Cases where a `some_verb` *and* all its `prefix+some_verb`s can *all* be either strong or weak (which seems to be the sitch with "schallen"/"beschallen") are a *different* type of exception that I need to deal with... "zurückweichen"/["weichen", "einweichen"] is exactly the kinda example I was looking for, though. "beringen"/"ringen" looks like it too, at least according to some sources. (Sorry, I'm being picky about what constitutes an actual answer for reasons that are a bit complicated to explain. xD )

Comment: @chirlu I added your examples at the end of the original question, with links. (For my own notes if nothing else, heh. :P ) Tell me if you think of any more examples like that. ^^

Comment: _beschallen_ can only be weak (I think).